# Why isn't this replace in DataFrame doing what I intended?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace NaN in `train_df` with values of corresponding indexes in `dff`. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
train_df.replace(to_replace = train_df["Age"].values , 
                 value = dff["Age"].values , 
                 inplace = True , 
                 regex = False , 
                 limit = None)

dff.Age.mean()
```

Output : 30.128401985359698

```
train_df.Age.mean()
```

Output : 28.96758312013303

Comment: can you provide same data (as dataframe) and expected output

Comment: Because `replace()` isn't the command that replaces NaNs, `fillna()` is, as L3n95 says. There's nothing in your code to say 'only do this on NaN rows', why do you expect your code would ony replace NaN values, not all values?

Comment: i thought it would do the same thing therefore , there's nothing about NaN. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace everything in `train_df` not just `NaN`.

The [`replace` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) say:

> Replace values given in to_replace with value.

If you just want to replace the `NaN` you should take a look at `fillna` or maybe you could use indexing with `isna`.

[`fillna` Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

[`isna` Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

**Example with fillna**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [5, 5, 3, 5]})
df1.fillna(df2, inplace=True)
```

**Example with isna**

```
df1[pd.isna(df1)] = df2
```

**Results**

```
>> df1
   a
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
```